# getting unexpected typer error in returing object array

Tags: java, arrays

Why am I getting an unexpected type error in line 22 when I try to return an object array?

```
public class StudentDemo {
public static void main(String args[]){

    StudentDemo program = new StudentDemo();
    program.start();
}

public void start(){
    Student one = new Student(1, "x", 80.0);
    Student two = new Student(2, "y", 81.0);
    Student three = new Student(3,"z", 79.5);
    Student four = new Student(4, "a", 85.0);
    Student five = new Student(5, "b", 86.0);
    Student arr[] = {one,two,three,four,five};
    Student[] splitarr = splitStudentArray(arr, char 'e'); //line 22
    splitarr[0].getName();
}

public Student[] splitStudentArray(Student arr[], char choice){

    Student[] splitArr = new Student[5];
    if(choice == 'e'){

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            if(arr[i].getMarks()%2 == 0){
                splitArr[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    else if(choice == 'o'){

        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
            if(arr[i].getMarks()%2 != 0){
                splitArr[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return splitArr;
}
}
```

The error says:

> required: value found: class.

Please help me out to find the error and why it is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
Student[] splitarr = splitStudentArray(arr, char 'e');
```

to

```
Student[] splitarr = splitStudentArray(arr,'e');
```

You don't specify the type of a variable (char in your case) when calling a method.